# How to change and add new HTML objects with Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom, object

I know a bit of PHP and so also HTML/CSS, and I have made a simple quiz program allowing users to create and do quizzes that are stored in a MySQL database. Now what I am trying to do is improve the usability and efficiency of the program.

On the createQuestions form, there are eight textboxes, users can fill in between 2 or 8 of these boxes with answers. Although I think this looks messy with all eight, and what I would like is to have 2 textboxes, and when there is text in the second one, the third one appears and so on.. up to eight

I spent a few hours learning a bit of basic JS, and managed to get it, so that there was a button that changed the visibility propities of the input box, label and radio button of each row. Although I wrote it really inefficiently lots of lines of code to do not much :p  - giving each object a separate ID, and it still didn't work that well.

Below is an example of how my HTML is laid out, I have eight of these, though I could replace this with one, and a PHP for loop with a limit of 8.

```
<div id="c">
<p class="subFont" id="cT" style="display:none;">Answer 3</p>
<input type="text" name="optionC"  class="textbox" style="display:none;" id="cI">
<input type="radio" name="correctAns" value="c" id="cR" style="display:none;">
<input type ="button" name="add" value="d" style="background-color:green;" onclick="addBox('d', 'inline')" id="cB" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to write the script descried above? Please could you comment or briefly explain your workings, so I can learn from it :)

Thank you loads in advance, I'm so grateful to all you guys on stackoverflow ;)

ps, any suggestions for learning js resources?

Comment: I would recommend looking into jQuery or other such library instead of using pure js for this. It'll save you tons of time. The basic idea is that you hide your inputs except for the first two and when user starts typing into the second one, third one will show and so on. I will not recommend adding/removing elements. If you do hide/show instead of append/remove it will work if js is disabled, and generally will be less buggy, me thinks.

Comment: Okay, looking into it now, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure Javascript

to hide/show object id="cR"

```
// hide
document.getElementById('cR').style.display = 'none';

// show
document.getElementById('cR').style.display = 'block';
```

to append textarea to

```
document.getElementById('c').innerHTML += '<textarea name=".." id=".."></textarea>';
```

events:

```
<input type="text" id="xxx" onchange="your action here" />
```

### jQuery

to hide/show object id="cR"

```
// hide
$('#cR').hide();
$('#cR').fadeIn(); // with fade in effect

// show
$('#cR').show();
$('#cR').fadeOut(); // width fade out effect
```

to append textarea to

```
$('#c').append('<textarea name=".." id=".."></textarea>');
```

events:

```
$('#xxx').change(function() {
    your action here
});
```

Comment: +1 for posting the jQuery solution. By the way jQuery=JavaScript, so I would change the first title to `Pure JavaScript` ;)

Answer (score -1):

another way to add element dynamically in page..

```
    <html>
       <head>
        <script>

            function addElement(obj) {
                text_limit = 5; // limit text then add text after that.    
                var text_lenght = obj.value.length;
                if(text_lenght >= text_limit){

                    var mainElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
                    var counter= mainElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea').length;
                    var newTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
                    var textareaname = 'txt_area'+counter;
                    newTextArea.setAttribute('id',textareaname );
                    newTextArea.onkeydown= function() {
                        addElement(this);
                    } 
                    mainElement.appendChild(newTextArea);

                }
            }

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="myDiv">
                <textarea id="txt_area2" onkeyup="addElement(this);"></textarea></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: onkeydown is wrong, innerHTML is wrong. `<script>` in `<html>` is wrong